# MariaDB my.cnf settings medium->heavy traffic

Tags: configuration, load, settings, mariadb

Could someone help me with a problem I have!? It is involving MariaDB configuration.
I have a server that has E5-Xeon CPU, 96GB DDR3 RAM, SSD Storage Space (1.2TB).
Recently something weird is happening. Some pages load very slow, other go instant. The pages that load slow include SELECT or INSERT queries.
Most of the tables are using MyISAM, but i also have InnoDB.
My.cnf file is kinda the default one and I was wondering what settings should i use.
I am using MySQL version 10.0.23-MariaDB.
The site has around 15.000 members. But never more than 1500-2500 online at the same time.
Thank you for any help i get :)

Answer (score 1):

There are far too many possibilities to answer your question without more info.  But here are the 'most important' settings:

For 96GB RAM and a mixture of InnoDB and MyISAM:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 16
key_buffer_size = 9G
```

The key_buffer does not need to be bigger than the sum all MyISAM indexes.  [Reference](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory).

For more info, turn on the slow log, wait a while, then summarize using `pt-query-digest` or `mysqldumpslow -s t` to see the top couple of queries.  Then focus on optimizing them in some way.  Often it is simple as devising the optimal composite index.

What is `Max_used_connections`?  If it is really `1500-2500`, then you have one set of issues.

Do *not* set `query_cache_size` bigger than, say, 100M.  That is a known performance killer.

If you tweaked any other 'variables', fess up.

For further critique of your settings, provide me with `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`.

MyISAM only has "table locking", which can slow things down; converting to InnoDB is likely to help.  [More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).